# Get $index number of ng-repeat in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I have 1 ng-repeat that and input filed on ng-change :

```
$scope.roomsHotel = '',
$scope.roomsOption = ['1','2','3','4','5']
$scope.numberRoom = function(index){
  $scope.roomCount =this.roomsHotel
}
```

and in view have ng-repeat that track by `$index` :

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="rooms in roomsOption | limitTo: roomCount track by $index">
```

and inside this ng-repeat I have some md-select that I need to validate before submit :

```
<div>
  <md-input-container class="md-block col-md-12" flex>
    <label>Bed Type </label>
    <md-select 
      ng-model="bedType[$index]"
      name="bedType{{$index}}"
      ng-required="true"
      ng-change="bed()">
      <md-option 
        ng-repeat="bed in bedOption" 
        ng-model="bedHotel"
        ng-value="bed"
        ng-messages>{{bed}}
      </md-option>
    </md-select>
    <div
      ng-messages="hotelForm['bedType'+$index].$error"
      ng-if="hotelForm['bedType'+$index].$invalid &&
        (submitted || hotelForm['bedType'+$index].$touched)">
      <div ng-message="required">Type of bed is require</div>
    </div>
  </md-input-container>
</div>
```

for ng-message its no problem I can make it work but on controller I need to validate before submit but `bedType0` and `bedType1` and so on give me undefined :

```
$scope.submitHotelsCtrl = function( numberOfRooms, bedType,$index) {
  $scope.submitted = true;
  if ($scope.hotelForm.numberOfRooms.$valid &&
    $scope.hotelForm.bedType.$$rawModelValue.$valid) {
    console.log('hi')}
  }
```

I try loop throw `roomsOption` or other way but Non of them work and here is I try to make on [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/eJgGhdwaDrK4oVwJZ196?p=preview) any help will save my day

Answer (score 0):

You have few problems in your code that you have provided in plunker,

1) your submitHotelsCtrl function takes some parameters but you are not sending any, you should at least pass $index to your function since you are using it in there.

html

```
<md-button class="md-accent md-raised" ng-click="submitHotelsCtrl($index)" id="submit" >search</md-button>
```

js

```
$scope.submitHotelsCtrl = function(index) {
}
```

2) even if you send $index since your button is outside the scope of ng-repeat $index will be undefined, therefore you should either move your button inside ng-repeat or use some other number.

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="rooms in roomsOption | limitTo: roomCount track by $index">
    <md-button class="md-accent md-raised" ng-click="submitHotelsCtrl($index)" id="submit" >search</md-button>    
</div>
```

3) you should change the code where you are trying to get property by name

from

```
$scope.hotelForm.bedType$index.$valid
```

to

```
$scope.hotelForm['bedType'+index].$valid
```

Comment: thanks for answer I pass `$index` to submit and for test change button inside but not working for change syntax I test before and change again not working and still undefine